# How to Generate & Group random hexadecimal numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

What is the easiest way to generate some random letters and numbers using hexadecimal?

Eg: `095904e8-121098-fb330c52-9ae4-4a44-a31d-b80f2c680ca0`

Comment: are you sure you don't want hexadecimal figures?

Comment: You can create random hexadecimal numbers: `Number(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(16, number_of_figures))).toString(16)` - but note that `number_of_figures` can't be bigger than 8 due to limited numerical precision.

Comment: @le_m Thanks it works. Can you add it as an answer, https://jsfiddle.net/Lqsqpnqt/

Answer (score 2):

by js without regex

```js
function randomString(len) {
　　len = len || 32;
　　var $chars = 'abcdefhiklmnorstuvwxz0123456789';
　　var maxPos = $chars.length;
　　var pwd = '';
　　for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
　　　　pwd += $chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * maxPos));
　　}
　　return pwd;
}
document.write(randomString(8)+'-'+randomString(6)+'-'+randomString(8)+'-'+randomString(4)+'-'+randomString(4)+'-'+randomString(4)+'-'+randomString(12));
```